# updating access with values in datagrid

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Not able to update the table in access using the below function

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click


Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(Con)
        Dim objUpdateCommand As New OleDbCommand
        Dim objDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        cn.Open()
        Const SQLExpression As String = "UPDATE product SET Value = @pValue where owner = @powner and Item = @pItem;"
        objUpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQLExpression, cn)

        With objUpdateCommand
            .Parameters.Add("@powner", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "owner")
            .Parameters.Add("@pItem", OleDbType.VarChar, 8, "Item")
            .Parameters.Add("@pValue", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "Value")
        End With

        objDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = objUpdateCommand

        MsgBox("Table Updated")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the updateCommand property doesn't execute the command.  You need to call the update method of the table adapter.

See more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233819%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have an adapter to just run an update statement with or without parameters.
Replace your code (objDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = objUpdateCommand) with this:

```
Dim UpdateResultValue as Integer

UpdateResultValue = objUpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery

If UpdateResultValue = 0 Then
   msgbox "Table Update Failed"
Else
   msgbox "Table Updated"
End if
```

If you a zero is returned, it didn't work (UpdateResultValue = 0). ExecuteNonQuery is used when you are not returning values from the database tables(probably over-simplified).

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters need to be in same order they are used in your query.

Comment: My parameters are in the same order as in the query.. My query is: Const SQLExpression As String = "UPDATE product SET Value = @pValue where owner = @powner and Item = @pItem;" and my order is : With objUpdateCommand .Parameters.Add("@pValue", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "Value") .Parameters.Add("@powner", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "owner") .Parameters.Add("@pItem", OleDbType.VarChar, 8, "Item") End With

Comment: Error am getting now is: Parameter @Value has no default value

Comment: Set the command type to Text `objUpdateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text` Instead of `objDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = objUpdateCommand` use `objUpdateCommand.ExecuteScalar()`. Also step through your code line by line and make sure the parameters have the values you expect them to.